# What is a correct way to insert a service variable into component of Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it a good idea to use a service variable in a template of a component like  in a code below?
The problem is that when I try to define this variable in a component itself like this: `usersList = this.service.arr` and then use in a template like this: `ngFor = let item of usersList`.
   It does not work without some additional steps - using Subject , for example.

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
    arr: SomeObject[];

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getUsers() {
        this.http.get('someUrl')
            .subscribe(
                res => arr as SomeObject[])
    };
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-smth',
    templateUrl: template: `
    <ul *ngFor = "let item of service.arr">
    <li>Name: {{item.name}}</li>
  </ul>  `
})

export class CategoryComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    constructor(private service: SomeService) { }
```

Comment: `service.arr` will **never** be anything but `undefined` in your example, your subscription doesn't actually assign to it. Expose an *observable* if the value isn't going to be available at first.

Comment: o. of cause it is my mistake. It should be like this:
                res => res = arr as SomeObject[]. And it works in a proper way.

Answer (score 0):

You should return an Observable from the service and either subscribe in the component or use the `async` pipe in the template of the component.

Example with the `async` pipe

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getUsers(): Observable<SomeObj[]> {
        return this.http.get('someUrl');
    }
}
```

Component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-smth',
    templateUrl: template: `
    <ul *ngFor = "let item of data$ | async">
    <li>Name: {{item.name}}</li>
  </ul>`
})
export class CategoryComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    data$: Observable<SomeObj[]> = this.service.getUsers();

    constructor(private service: SomeService) { }
}
```